# Abstract Parent to use Child's Aliases

Tags: php, inheritance, namespaces

Is it possible to alias a class in a child, and to use that alias within the abstract class which it inherits from.

See code below as an example.

Abstract class using the `Model` class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

abstract class ResourceController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $model = Model::all();

        return view('backend.pages.'.$this->name.'.index', [
            'models' => $model
        ]);
    }

?>
```

Child:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend;

use App\Http\Requests\Review as Request;
use App\Models\Review as Model;

class ReviewsController extends ResourceController
{
    protected $name = 'reviews';
}

?>
```

Ultimately my intention is to have a `ResourceController` with methods blind to that of its children's classes so I can inherit it and simply alias which Model and Request to use.

I have perused the docs and couldn't find what I am after I assume there should be a way to do this but I must be overlooking something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: no. Aliases are literals with a defined scope, and it would be madness if their meaning wasn't literal and unpredictable.

That's basically the reason why you don't use `static` class methods, but instances. If you'd write `$this->model->all()`, it would be trivial and obvious how a subclass can override that behaviour.

The best you can do with using static classes is something like:

```
abstract class ResourceController extends Controller {
    abstract function getModelClass();

    public function index() {
        $class = $this->getModelClass();
        $model = $class::all();
    }
}

class ReviewsController extends ResourceController {
    function getModelClass() {
        return Model::class;
    }
}
```

But then again, you should give yourself even more flexibility and do this instead:

```
abstract class ResourceController extends Controller {
    abstract function getAll();

    public function index() {
        $model = $this->getAll();
    }
}
```